# сохранение cookie javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

привет я хочу чтобы ответ result сохранился в cookie  но чтобы он показался не с помочью alert а просто вывести
как php `<?php echo $_COOKIE["questi"]; ?>`

```js
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
  start = document.getElementById('start'),
  stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
  clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
  seconds = 0,
  minutes = 0,
  hours = 0,
  result = document.getElementById('result'),
 // x = document.cookie = result, // Commented
  t;


function add() {
  seconds++;
  if (seconds >= 60) {
    seconds = 0;
    minutes++;
    if (minutes >= 60) {
      minutes = 0;
      hours++;
    }
  }

  h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) :
    "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

  timer();
}

function timer() {
  t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
timer();


/* Start button */
start.onclick = timer;

/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
  clearTimeout(t)
  time();

}

/* Clear button */
clear.onclick = function() {
  h1.textContent = "00:00:00";
  seconds = 0;
  minutes = 0;
  hours = 0;
}

function time() {

  if (seconds >= 1 && seconds <= 30) {
    result.textContent = 1;
    result();
  }
  if (seconds >= 35 && seconds <= 40) {
    result.textContent = 9;
  }

  result();
 // document.cookie = result; // commented
}
```

```html
<h1><time>00:00:00</time></h1>
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<button id="clear">clear</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```js
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
  start = document.getElementById('start'),
  stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
  clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
  seconds = 0,
  minutes = 0,
  hours = 0,
  result = document.getElementById('result'),
 // x = document.cookie = result, // Commented
  t;


function add() {
  seconds++;
  if (seconds >= 60) {
    seconds = 0;
    minutes++;
    if (minutes >= 60) {
      minutes = 0;
      hours++;
    }
  }

  h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) :
    "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

  timer();
}

function timer() {
  t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
timer();


/* Start button */
start.onclick = timer;

/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
  clearTimeout(t)
  time();

}

/* Clear button */
clear.onclick = function() {
  h1.textContent = "00:00:00";
  seconds = 0;
  minutes = 0;
  hours = 0;
  // Если нужно почистить и значение в поле result то:
  result.innerHTML = '';
}

function time() {

  if (seconds >= 1 && seconds <= 30) {
    result.innerHTML = '1';
    //result();
  }
  if (seconds >= 35 && seconds <= 40) {
    result.innerHTML = '9';
  }

  //result(); - это не функция, будет ошибка.
 // document.cookie = result; // commented
}
```

```html
<h1><time>00:00:00</time></h1>
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<button id="clear">clear</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: подскажи как result добавить в куки и считать ево, если добавить  document.cookie = 'cookie1=result ; так он не работает,  а если считать alert( document.cookie );  так он все куки  не работает все куки показывает,

Comment: @vladMathu На это есть jQ плагины, jQuery Cookie. Поизучай.